# Call a @Future method with the Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, future, invocable-method

I am attempting to call a class with a @Future method by using Process Builder. In order to do this I believe I need to initially call a class with an @InvocableMethod to in-turn call that @Future class. I could be wrong on that.

This is my @Future class which I am trying to run :

```
public class FutureApexCallout {
@future(callout=true) 
    public static void pardotCallout(String contactId) {
        
        String returnedResponseFromPardot = Http_Utility_Pardot.pardotCreateProspect(new Set<Id> {contactId});            
        }
}
```

I'm having problems trying to call that class. This is what I have so far, but I know it is not correct. I'm just trying to place the Contact__c field from my current record into call out :

```
public class MakeApexCallout {

  @InvocableMethod
   public static void invokeapexcallout(list<Program_Contact_Role__c> pcr) {
     Futureapexcallout.pardotcallout(pcr[0].contact__c);
   }    
   
}
```

But I'm getting this error for this MakeApexCallout class :

```
Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void pardotcallout(String, String, Id) from the type FutureApexCallout at line 5 column 24
```

I apologize ahead of time for rudimentary question. I'm a rookie just getting to know this.

I would be very grateful for any help I can get on this.

Comment: Just so I understand, what is the reason you want to call a future method? Is this to break the invocation into its own transaction to avoid mixed DML or callout constraints? If so, just calling an invocable method should do exactly that for you anyway since they are invoked in their own transaction via REST API.

Comment: It would be sensible to include a screenshot of the way you are configuring the invocable method invocation in the process builder too.

Comment: @PhilW - Yes, there is another class (called by the same Process Builder) which will be performing DML operations. Thus, the Future annotation. I can put in a screenshot if you'd like, but I just tell you that it is being initiated by the changing of a field in the Program_Contact_Role__c object. And I was thinking that I would set the contactid to the Contact__c field in the record. But I'm not sure how to do that. I'm getting the 'Method does not exist...' error I just added to the post. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: @PhilW - oh ! I just noticed the error was coming from incorrectly had the class name reference in all lower case.

Comment: @PhilW - that was it - it worked ! Let me know if you don't understand the Process Builder part and I'll put some screenshots up if you want.